# Difference in outputs while printing value stored in a variable and printing value directly using printf()

Tags: c, variables, printf, difference

I am trying to write a simple C program that takes the input from user in metres and prints the output in kilometres, yards and miles **rounded to 4 decimal places.**

I have used this **1 meter = 0.001 kilometers = 1.094 yards = 0.0006215 miles**

When I write this, I get the output as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int m;
   float km, y, mi;
   scanf("%d",&m);
   km=(m*0.001);
   y=(m*1.094);
   mi=(m*0.0006215);
   printf("%.4f\n%.4f\n%.4f",km,y,mi);
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

0.1000

109.4000

0.0622

**But, when I write this I get the third output wrong:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int m;
   scanf("%d",&m);
   printf("%.4f\n%.4f\n%.4f",(m*0.001),(m*1.094),(m*0.0006215));
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

0.1000

109.4000

***0.0621***

Can you please help me find the reason for this difference?

---

**Edit-1**

here I gave input 100.

```
float y=100*0.0006215;
printf("%f",y);
```

gave output 0.062150

and this

```
printf("%f",100*0.0006215);
```

also gave output 0.062150

---

**Edit-2**

```
float y=100*0.0006215;
printf("%.4f",y);
```

gave output **0.0622**

while:

```
printf("%.4f",100*0.0006215);
```

gave output **0.0621**

**whereas in Edit-1 both displayed the same output.**

Comment: I am not able to relate "Is floating point math broken?" question with my question. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that `0.001` is a `double` value.

In the first example you assigned the `double` result to `float`, truncating its significance, which was then promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`.

In the second example, there is no `float`, the `double` results are passed directly to `printf`.

Also, please see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: here I gave input 100:   

    float y=100*0.0006215;
 printf("%f",y);
gave output 0.062150

and this

    printf("%f",100*0.0006215);
also gave output 0.062150

**Then why does using "%.4f" in both the cases gave different answer?** I see that you mentioned there is no float in 2nd example but I see the output containing 6 decimal places, indicating a float rather than a double. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please see the edit in question for better understanding of my question

Comment: Because the numbers are different, and they were rounded differently.

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get it. Please see Edit-2. I hope that would be able to explain my question in a better way to you.

Comment: If you print with 9 decimal places you get `0.062150002` and `0.062150000` so I would guess that the library code is rounding `5` or less down, and rounding more than `5` up, since when you ask for 4 decimal places, there is that `5xxxx` to be rounded. Please remember that with floating point fractions, you will usually get only an *approximation* of the number, not an *exact* number. That is the relevance of the "broken" link.